# On entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$  be an entire function. Then which of the following is/are true?

$(1) \lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}z=0$ implies $f$ is constant

$(2) \lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{Re(f(z))}z=0$ implies $f$ is constant

For $(1)$ , I think it is true and I could think of two ways of showing that.

Proof$(a)$:- Let $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$ be the power sereis expansion of $f(z)$ .

Then for $z\neq 0$,

$\frac{f(z)}z=\frac{a_0}z+a_1+a_2z+..$

Since the $\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}z$ exist finitely and equals zero we must have $a_1=a_2=a_3=...=0$

Hence $f(z)=a_0$ , a constant.

Proof$(b)$ Assuming  $f(z)$ is non constant entire, $z=\infty$ is either essential singularity i.e $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)$ does not exist (either finitely or infinitely). or $z=\infty$ is a pole singularity of some order .

If $z=\infty$ is a  pole singularity, then

$0=\lim_{z\to \infty}\frac{f(z)}z[\equiv \frac{\infty}{\infty}]$

$=\lim_{z\to \infty}f'(z)$ (after L-Hospital's rule)

Since $f'(z)$ is entire and $z=\infty$ is removable singularity of $f'(z)$, so $f'(z)=0 \forall z$ and thus giving $f(z)$ is constant.

I am hoping the case for $z=\infty$ being essential singularity in proof$(b)$ to be completed but failed to do anything about it.

For the part $(2)$, I tried showing $Re(f(z)) $ is bounded
and from the limit , I just have for an arbitary $\epsilon \gt 0$

$|Ref(z))|\lt \epsilon |z| ,\quad \forall z$ with $|z|\ge M$ for some $M$ .

I have no idea after this.

Do you have any suggestions for me? Thanks for your time.

Comment: For part 2, Borel-Caratheodory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem applied with $R, 2R$ gives a bound $||f||_{R} \le 2||u||_{2R}+$constant, where $u =\Re f, ||.||_R$ is the maximum on the closed disc of radius $R$; this implies that if $||u||_R=o(R)$ then $||f||_R=o(R)$ so one can apply part 1

Comment: I see, Thanks sir.

Comment: You did not explain how you got $a_k = 0$ above, there is a bit of a leap. A better approach would be to show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 1$ and then show that it is in fact a constant.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok ..will this work? From the limit, $|f(z)| \lt A|z|$ for sufficiently large $z$ . Then over  $\gamma:|z|=R$ , $a_n=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$ which gives $|a_n|\le \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{gamma}\frac{AR}{R^{n+1}}=n!\frac{A}{R^{n-1}} \to 0$ , as $R\to \infty$, if $n\ge 2$ , thus implying $f(z)$ is polynomial of.degree at most $1$.

Comment: @copper.hat..Sorry I couldn't put it up in a comment , but is my overall idea correct?

Comment: @student: Sure, or just use Cauchy's estimate directly.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.